# Ext.Js model store objects

Tags: javascript, extjs, model, store, sencha-architect

How can I adopt my ext js models to hold data containing objects.

Data example:

```
fruit {
    apples {
        quantity: '10',
        color: 'red
    }
    pears {
        color:'yellow',
        taste: 'very bad'
    }
```

How would then my model look like? I only know how to put data on one level:

```
Ext.define('app.mode.Fruits', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'apples'
        },
        {
            name: 'pears'
        },
    ],
```

Where can I put the other properties? I am working in Sencha Architect.

Comment: You can use associations and then you have the other model.  that is, i believe you are looking for hasOne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a read through the [Ext.data.Field](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field) API docs. You'll see a variety of ways in which to configure data on your model.

I think what you're specifically asking for is the [mapping](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-mapping) config.